# how to modify the python code to save the files with the date and time as the filename for each date data

Tags: python, date, time

i want to modify my code to give the date and time as the file name. the data is in text file as following. i want each data set have the date of corresponding data.save the file withe date as the file name.how to modify the given code to achieve this.
the current code write and save the file of each day with the filename of indices. i want to change that and save the file with the date and time of the data

the data is

```
43371 Thiruvananthapuram Observations at 00Z 04 Mar 2023
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   PRES   HGHT   TEMP   DWPT   RELH   MIXR   DRCT   SKNT   THTA   THTE   THTV
    hPa     m      C      C      %    g/kg    deg   knot     K      K      K 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  956.0     64   24.2   13.2     50  10.07    105      2  301.2  331.2  303.0
  928.0    323   21.8   11.8     53   9.45     97      4  301.3  329.5  303.0
  904.0    551   21.8   10.8     50   9.07     90      7  303.6  330.9  305.2
  877.0    813   19.0    9.0     52   8.28     82      9  303.3  328.3  304.8
  869.0    891   19.0    7.4     47   7.47     80     10  304.1  326.8  305.5
  846.0   1121   19.0    2.6     33   5.47    105     17  306.4  323.5  307.5
  820.0   1389   19.0   -3.0     22   3.76    114     22  309.2  321.2  309.9
  819.0   1400   17.8    0.8     32   4.98    114     22  308.0  323.7  309.0
  810.0   1494   17.4    8.4     55   8.61    118     24  308.6  335.1  310.2
  803.0   1567   16.9    8.2     57   8.56    120     25  308.8  335.2  310.4
  708.0   2628    8.8    5.1     78   7.84    112     20  311.2  335.7  312.7
  679.0   2974    8.4    3.0     69   7.02    110     18  314.4  336.8  315.8
  669.0   3097    8.2    2.2     66   6.75    103     16  315.6  337.2  316.9
  644.0   3408    5.5    0.0     68   5.99     85     12  316.0  335.3  317.1
  618.0   3746    2.6   -2.3     70   5.26    104     16  316.4  333.4  317.4
  596.0   4038    1.1   -3.4     72   5.00    120     20  318.0  334.3  318.9
  580.0   4257    0.0   -4.3     73   4.82    121     19  319.1  335.0  320.1
  557.0   4581   -0.7  -13.7     37   2.40    123     18  322.0  330.3  322.5
  539.0   4842   -2.7  -14.8     39   2.27    125     17  322.7  330.6  323.1
  537.0   4872   -2.9  -14.9     39   2.25    121     16  322.8  330.6  323.2
  518.0   5157   -2.7  -23.7     18   1.10     81      8  326.4  330.4  326.6
  508.0   5310   -4.0  -24.5     19   1.04     60      4  326.6  330.5  326.9
  474.0   5853   -8.5  -27.5     20   0.85                327.6  330.7  327.7
  410.0   6963  -15.1  -36.1     15   0.43                332.9  334.6  333.0
Station information and sounding indices
                             Station number: 43371
                           Observation time: 230304/0000
                           Station latitude: 8.48
                          Station longitude: 76.95
                          Station elevation: 64.0
                            Showalter index: 9.33
                               Lifted index: 6.19
    LIFT computed using virtual temperature: 5.83
                                    K index: 23.27
                         Cross totals index: 8.43
                      Vertical totals index: 24.01
                        Totals totals index: 32.44
      Convective Available Potential Energy: 0.00
             CAPE using virtual temperature: 0.00
                      Convective Inhibition: 0.00
             CINS using virtual temperature: 0.00
                     Bulk Richardson Number: 0.00
          Bulk Richardson Number using CAPV: 0.00
  Temp [K] of the Lifted Condensation Level: 282.71
Pres [hPa] of the Lifted Condensation Level: 795.29
   Equivalent potential temp [K] of the LCL: 330.19
     Mean mixed layer potential temperature: 301.85
              Mean mixed layer mixing ratio: 9.52
Precipitable water [mm] for entire sounding: 30.51
43371 Thiruvananthapuram Observations at 00Z 05 Mar 2023
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   PRES   HGHT   TEMP   DWPT   RELH   MIXR   DRCT   SKNT   THTA   THTE   THTV
    hPa     m      C      C      %    g/kg    deg   knot     K      K      K 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1006.0     64   25.6   22.7     84  17.61      0      0  298.2  349.6  301.4
 1004.0     81   26.4   17.4     58  12.61     30      1  299.2  336.2  301.5
 1000.0    116   26.4   17.4     58  12.66     90      2  299.6  336.8  301.8
  964.0    440   25.8   16.8     58  12.64     86      8  302.1  339.7  304.4
  955.0    522   25.0   16.7     60  12.65     85     10  302.1  339.7  304.4
  931.0    745   22.8   16.3     67  12.67    100     12  302.0  339.7  304.3
  925.0    802   22.2   16.2     69  12.68    100     13  302.0  339.7  304.3
  868.0   1350   18.1   14.2     78  11.84     85     12  303.3  338.7  305.5
  850.0   1531   16.8   13.5     81  11.57     95     12  303.7  338.4  305.8
  814.0   1899   14.2   11.3     83  10.43    106     19  304.8  336.2  306.7
  770.0   2365   12.6    8.5     76   9.15    120     29  307.9  335.9  309.6
  700.0   3165    9.8    3.8     66   7.23    105     17  313.3  336.2  314.7
  692.0   3261    9.8    3.8     66   7.32    105     16  314.3  337.5  315.7
  689.0   3296    9.5    3.7     67   7.27    105     15  314.4  337.5  315.8
  658.0   3674    6.8    2.1     72   6.84     70     11  315.5  337.3  316.8
  623.0   4123    3.5    0.4     80   6.35     95      6  316.7  337.1  317.9
  620.0   4163    3.2    0.2     81   6.30     92      6  316.8  337.1  318.0
  591.0   4550    1.0   -2.8     76   5.30     67      6  318.6  335.9  319.6
  574.0   4785    1.2   -9.8     44   3.18     52      6  321.5  332.3  322.1
  525.0   5496   -3.7  -13.7     46   2.54      6      6  323.9  332.7  324.4
  520.0   5571   -2.9  -22.9     20   1.17      1      6  325.8  330.0  326.0
  500.0   5880   -5.5  -24.5     21   1.06    340      6  326.3  330.1  326.5
  467.0   6410  -10.5  -23.5     34   1.24                326.5  331.0  326.7
  455.0   6611   -9.7  -32.7     13   0.54                329.9  332.0  330.0
  446.0   6765  -10.3  -39.3      7   0.29                331.1  332.2  331.1
Station information and sounding indices
                             Station number: 43371
                           Observation time: 230305/0000
                           Station latitude: 8.48
                          Station longitude: 76.95
                          Station elevation: 64.0
                            Showalter index: 2.06
                               Lifted index: 1.99
    LIFT computed using virtual temperature: 1.45
                                SWEAT index: 192.01
                                    K index: 29.80
                         Cross totals index: 19.00
                      Vertical totals index: 22.30
                        Totals totals index: 41.30
      Convective Available Potential Energy: 0.00
             CAPE using virtual temperature: 0.00
                      Convective Inhibition: 0.00
             CINS using virtual temperature: -315.28
 Equilibrum Level using virtual temperature: 466.48
             LFCT using virtual temperature: 468.72
                     Bulk Richardson Number: 0.00
          Bulk Richardson Number using CAPV: 0.00
  Temp [K] of the Lifted Condensation Level: 288.26
Pres [hPa] of the Lifted Condensation Level: 860.18
   Equivalent potential temp [K] of the LCL: 338.49
     Mean mixed layer potential temperature: 300.95
              Mean mixed layer mixing ratio: 12.74
              1000 hPa to 500 hPa thickness: 5764.00
Precipitable water [mm] for entire sounding: 44.38
```

the code used is

```
data_file_path = 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\trial.txt'
output_folder_path = 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\'

with open(data_file_path, 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()  # Read all lines into a list

    # Find all occurrences of '43371'
    indices = []
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if 'Thiruvananthapuram' in line:
            indices.append(i)

    if len(indices) > 0:
        for idx in indices:
            # Find the line containing 'Station' after 4 lines of '43371'
            station_index = None
            for i in range(idx + 5, len(lines)):
                if 'Station' in lines[i]:
                    station_index = i
                    break

            if station_index is not None:
                # Create the output file path
                output_file_path = output_folder_path + f"output{idx}.txt"

                with open(output_file_path, 'w') as output_file:
                    # Write the data from idx+5 to station_index (excluding both lines)
                    for line in lines[idx + 5:station_index]:
                        output_file.write(line)

                print(f"The data after 4 lines of 'Thiruvananthapuram' has been written to {output_file_path}")
            else:
                print("'Station' not found after 4 lines of 'Thiruvananthapuram'")
    else:
        print("'Thiruvananthapuram' not found in the data file")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to get the date from the line that contains Thiruvananthapuram assuming that the date will always be present in that line in the same format.

Something like this:

```
import re

if 'Thiruvananthapuram' in line:
    match = re.search("([0-9]{2} [A-Z][a-z]{2} [0-9]{4})", line)
    if match:
        indices.append(match[0])
```

Comment: i want to find the data and use it as the file name for each data set

Comment: Yes, just replace the lines:

        if 'Thiruvananthapuram' in line:
            indices.append(i)

with the code above